# Don't understand code that gets random number between two values

Tags: math, random, logic

So, I understand this seems like a stupid question. With that said however, within my classes concerned with teaching proper code. I came upon this. `Min + (Math.random() * ((Max - Min) + 1))` Essentially the code goes. Add your minimum value + a random number between 0.0 and 1.0 multiplied by the max value minus the minimum value plus 1. The book regards this code as a base for retrieving a random value within certain parameters. i.e max=40 min=20. That would get a value between 40 and 20.

The thing is, I know what the code is saying and doing. I was using this to generate a random character by adding (char) to the front and using 'a' and 'z' as the values. The thing is though, I don't understand how, mathematically speaking, this even works. I understand it makes me a pretty poor programmer on my part. I never claimed to be great or brilliant. I know algebra and some basic higher math concepts but there are some stupidly basic formulas like this that leave me scratching my head.

In terms of programming logic, this isn't so much an issue for me, but seeing concepts like this. I'm confused. I don't get the mathematical logic of this code. Am I missing anything? I mean, with a math random value between 0.0 and 1.0, I don't see how it procures a value between the minimum and maximum value. Would anybody be willing to be give me a layman's explanation of how this works?

Comment: Thank you, your explanation was helpful in explaining the function. It's nice just to know that it has a name really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is called **linear interpolation** or sometimes even **linear extrapolation** depends if you are enlarging or shrinking dynamic range. Anyway the idea behind dynamic range changing is this:

let have:

```cpp
x = < x0 , x1 > // input range
```

And we want to change them to

```cpp
y = < y0 , y1 > // output range
```

So let me derive it step by step:

```cpp
// equation                           range         operation
y = x                          // < x0 , x1    >   -x0
y = x-x0                       // < 0  , x1-x0 >   /(x1-x0)
y = (x-x0)/(x1-x0)             // < 0  , 1     >   *(y1-y0)
y = (y1-y0)(x-x0)/(x1-x0)      // < 0  , y1-y0 >   +y0
y = y0 + (y1-y0)(x-x0)/(x1-x0) // < y0 , y1    >
```

Now I suspect `x=Math().random()` returns values `x=<0,1>` and we want result in `<y0,y1> = <min,max>` then:

```cpp
y = min + (max-min)(x-0)/(1-0)
y = min + (max-min)*x
```

The `+1` resulting in `<min,max+1>` range or in case your `Random()<1` restores range from `<min,max)` back to `<min,max>` hard to say without context (I do not code in your language assuming **JAVA** or something similar I am more of a **C++** guy)

For simplicity linear interpolation/extrapolation is to obtain values between two edges/points/values linearly with some parameter `t=<0,1>`

```
x(t) = x0 + (x1-x0)*t
```

if `(t=0)` then `x(0)=x0`

if `(t=1)` then `x(1)=x1`

if `(t=0.5)` then `x(0.5)=` middle between `x0` and `x1`

If `t=<0,1>` then we are talking about linear interpolation. If `t` is outside this range then we are talking about linear extrapolation (equation is the same).

Linear means when you sample points/values with constant `t` step then the resulting values will also have constant distance between them. And also lies on a single line ...

Hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine rubber fiber spanned between points 0 and 1 (line segment).
Sprinkle some dye drops on it - you have generated random values on 0..1 interval.
Now fix left point and stretch this fiber until its length becomes `Max - Min`.
Now shift it right by `Min`.
You can see some color points (random values) on interval `Min..Max`

In general this is linear transformation of one interval (`0..1`) into another (`Min..Max`). Note that initial interval might be arbitrary.